# AppleScript: How to extract section from string (based on defined characters)?

Tags: macos, applescript, text

Example:

`set theText to "I ate an apple at 11:54 pm without the skin."`

I would like `theTime` to be a string that contains the text: `11:54`

So, I would like the opening text item delimiter to be `at_` and the closing text item delimiter to be either `_pm` or `_am`, depending on which period exists in the string. (Note - Every instance of an underscore in this post is meant to represent a space because I am unable to represent a space in the Stack Exchange code formatting.)

The contents of `theText` will vary greatly. For example, it might be:

`set theText to "I ate two navel oranges at 6:30 am with a glass of water."`

But the time format will always remain constant. The time will always be preceded with an "at " and that "at " will always be the first instance of an "at " in the string. Similarly, the time will necessarily be followed by either " am" or " pm".

Comment: I have updated my original answer to include a space _before_ and _after_ the three _field separators_ (delimiters) " at ", " am " and " pm " as it makes more sense to do so and not just a single space as originally written.

Comment: I've update my answer again to show how a single line of _regular_ AppleScript _code_ does what the 8 lines of _pure_ AppleScript _code_ does in the other answer.

Comment: Nice, thanks. However I've realized that I actually prefer your original solution because it is more restrictive, as it exactly addressed my original question with a literal interpretation (like you noted). In general, I like to make as few assumptions as possible when I am writing code, to be conservative. While it may not be common or expected, a colon could potentially exist before the time in `theText` string, which would disorient a colon-based method of getting `theTime`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running the following AppleScript *code* in AppleScript Editor:

```
set theText to "I ate an apple at 11:54 pm without the skin."
set theTime to do shell script "awk -F ' at | am | pm ' '{print $2}'<<<" & quoted form of theText
log "The time was: " & theTime

set theText to "I ate two navel oranges at 6:30 am with a glass of water."
set theTime to do shell script "awk -F ' at | am | pm ' '{print $2}'<<<" & quoted form of theText
log "The time was: " & theTime
```

Produces the following output in the AppleScript Editor's Event Log:

```
tell current application
    do shell script "awk -F ' at | am | pm ' '{print $2}'<<<'I ate an apple at 11:54 pm without the skin.'"
        --> "11:54"
    (*The time was: 11:54*)
    do shell script "awk -F ' at | am | pm ' '{print $2}'<<<'I ate two navel oranges at 6:30 am with a glass of water.'"
        --> "6:30"
    (*The time was: 6:30*)
end tell
```

In the above examples I've defined the *field separators* (delimiters) in `awk` using the `-F` *option* as `' at | am | pm '` which equates to " at ", " am " and " pm " and it prints `'{print $2}'` what's between the *field separators*.

Note: The use of the `log` *command* is not necessary to the coding for the answer and is being used just to show what the *value* of `theTime` contains for the Event Log output aside from what's shown after `-->`, which is the *result* as normally shown in the Event Log.

---

Update: I wrote my original answer based on a literal interpretation in that when said, "*So, I would like the opening text item delimiter to be `at_` and the closing text item delimiter to be either `_pm` or `_am`*", what was wanted was to literally use those as the delimiters. However, since a different solution using *pure* AppleScript *code*, in a separate answer, was presented, let me present a one-line AppleScript *code* solution that does the same thing the 8 lines of *pure* AppleScript *code* does and by focusing on the *colon*, but as as part of a *RegEx* representation of the time in hours and minutes.

```
set theTime to do shell script "awk 'match($0,/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-5][0-9]/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'<<<" & quoted form of theText
```

Running the following AppleScript *code* in AppleScript Editor:

```
set theText to "I ate an apple at 11:54 pm without the skin."
set theTime to do shell script "awk 'match($0,/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-5][0-9]/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'<<<" & quoted form of theText

set theText to "I ate two navel oranges at 6:30 am with a glass of water."
set theTime to do shell script "awk 'match($0,/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-5][0-9]/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'<<<" & quoted form of theText
```

Produces the following output in the AppleScript Editor's Event Log:

```
tell current application
    do shell script "awk 'match($0,/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-5][0-9]/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'<<<'I ate an apple at 11:54 pm without the skin.'"
            --> "11:54"
    do shell script "awk 'match($0,/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-5][0-9]/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'<<<'I ate two navel oranges at 6:30 am with a glass of water.'"
            --> "6:30"
end tell
```

As you can see, whether or not there are one to two numbers preceding the colon the RegEx matches and the `awk` *program* returns the desired match, of which being the time.

Personally, I'd choose to use this particular method over my original answer, as it's a better method under the circumstances, and or over the *pure* AppleScript *code* as I can't justify writing 8 lines of *pure* AppleScript *code* when a single line of *regular* AppleScript *code* produces the same results as the 8 lines do!

Answer (score 6):

You can do it with pure AppleScript, even though the shell script method presented above is very nice:

```
set theText to "I ate an apple at 11:54 pm without the skin."
set the_colon_location to offset of ":" in theText
-- now we know where the colon is.
-- The Time is going to be on either side of it.
set the_starting_point to the_colon_location - 2
set the_ending_point to the_colon_location + 5
set the_time_string to characters the_starting_point thru the_ending_point of theText as string
-- in case the hour is not two digits, the first character will be a space
if character 1 of the_time_string is " " then
    set the_time_string to characters 2 thru -1 of the_time_string as string
end if
return the_time_string
```

Comment: It's always nice to know how to do the same thing in different ways, but when `set theTime to do shell script "awk 'match($0,/[0-9]{1,2}:[0-5][0-9]/) {print substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)}'<<<" & quoted form of theText` produces the same results in one line of _regular_ AppleScript _code_ that takes 8 lines of your _pure_ AppleScript _code_ to do, I don't believe I'd ever use your method. However, I have added it to my file of code snippets so as to have an example of the logic flow, in case I find a compelling reason to use it over an `awk` solution.

Comment: Totally understood. However, my answer was not meant to compete on speed or on line count. It was meant to be readable and understandable by as many people as possible. I completely tip my hat to the use of regular expressions in the other solution.